# How to brand / name a service group that include mobile, internet and ATM banking

Tags: banking

We would like to rebrand our alternative banking channels - To start with, we are trying to find a formal but easy to grasp name to represent internet banking, mobile banking and ATM banking. What would your suggestion be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two options:

- *Financial Services* or *"Financial Services for Everyone"* that consider "mobile", "online" and "ATM" natural for a bank in 2016;
- *Speed Banking*

Comment: Thank you so much! Speed Banking sounds really "out-of-the-box" to brand your self within the company, and I think I will shortlist this one. By the way, how can we elaborate on "Consumers" wording?

Comment: Actually, I will edit my answer because I think "Customers" add something specific and it is no need for that.

Comment: This is my answer UX related. For a complete solution, I think you must analyse the marketing facts, what you need to promote, what you offer. The name of category should be simple and then add something specific for your brand maybe.